# What is an ideal in topology?

Tags: general-topology

I am currently trying to prove a unique collection of subsets of I, where I is any nonempty set, is an ideal. I cannot find anything on the internet about an ideal in topology, I only find Algebra references. I can find the definition below but I cannot find any examples or anything. I was wondering if someone could help me understand an ideal in topology or point me to any books or articles that may help.

> An ideal $\mathscr{L}$ is a nonempty collection of sets in a topological space X such that $\mathscr{L}$ is closed under heredity and finite additivity, i.e. $\mathscr{L}$ satisfies the following properties:
>
> 1. $T \in \mathscr{L}$ and $S \subseteq T$ implies $S \in \mathscr{L}$
> 2. $S \in \mathscr{L}$ and $T \in \mathscr{L}$ implies $S \cup T \in \mathscr{L}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That definition tells you exactly what an ideal is in this context: it’s a family of sets in some space that is closed under taking subsets and closed under unions. For example, let $X$ be any infinite space, and let $\mathscr{F}$ be the family of all finite subsets of $X$; then $\mathscr{F}$ is an ideal.

- Subsets of finite sets are finite, so if $G\subseteq F\in\mathscr{F}$, then clearly $G$ is finite, and therefore $G\in\mathscr{F}$: $\mathscr{F}$ is closed under taking subsets.
- If $F,G\in\mathscr{F}$, then $F\cup G$ is finite, so $F\cup G\in\mathscr{F}$.

In particular, if $\tau$ is the cofinite topology (sometimes called the finite closed topology) on an infinite set $X$, then $\mathscr{F}=\{X\setminus U:U\in\tau\setminus\{\varnothing\}\}$: the closed proper subsets of $X$ form an ideal.

An easy and useful exercise is to prove that if $\mathscr{L}$ is an ideal, and $\mathscr{A}$ is a **finite** subset of $\mathscr{L}$, then $\bigcup\mathscr{A}\in\mathscr{L}$: an ideal is not closed just under taking simple unions of two of its members, but also under taking the union of any **finite** number of its members.

If you’re acquainted with the notion of a *filter* on a set $X$, you should verify that a family $\mathscr{L}$ of subsets of $X$ is an ideal if and only if $\{X\setminus L:L\in\mathscr{L}\}$ is a filter on $X$, and $\mathscr{U}$ is a filter on $X$ if and only if $\{X\setminus U:U\in\mathscr{U}\}$ is an ideal on $X$: ideals and filters are dual notions.

It’s worth noting that neither of these notions actually involves the topology: you define ideals and filters in this way on any set. In a specifically topological setting we sometimes look at slightly more general notions of ideal and filter that **do** involve the topology. We might, for instance, speak of an *ideal $\mathscr{C}$ of closed sets* in a space $X$, meaning that $\mathscr{C}$ is a family of closed subsets of $X$ such that

- if $H\subseteq C\in\mathscr{C}$, and $H$ is closed, then $H\in\mathscr{C}$, and
- if $C,D\in\mathscr{C}$, then $C\cup D\in\mathscr{C}$. (Of course $C\cup D$ is automatically closed if $C$ and $D$ are.)

**Added:** Henno Brandsma reminds me that the nowhere dense sets are an excellent genuinely topological example of an ideal on a topological space. Let $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ be a topological space; a set $N\subseteq X$ is nowhere dense if $\operatorname{cl}N$ does not contain any non-empty open set. (For example, $\Bbb Z$ is nowhere dense in $\Bbb R$: it is already closed, and its interior is empty.) Let

$$\mathscr{N}=\{N\subseteq X:N\text{ is nowhere dense}\}\,;$$

then $\mathscr{N}$ is an ideal, though I’ll leave it to you to check that it satisfies the defining properties.

Comment: Am I missing something or is it worth pointing out that the notion of ideal on a set $X$ here is not dependent on any topology on $X$?

Comment: @RobArthan: I was debating, but I probably should.

Comment: Maybe you could have mentioned a classical topological example: the set of all nowhere dense subsets of $X$. That’s at least topologically motivated.

Comment: @Henno: An excellent suggestion; I’ll add it and then shut down for the night.